# IIS cache control configuration not working properly

Tags: angular, iis, browser-cache, meta-tags, cache-control

I have an angular 8 site on IIS Windows Server 2012 R2 that is caching new builds on deployment to production. For example i changed a png image on the main dashboard and for some users it updated but others it remained as the old one.

I tried to create a web.config for cache control but it seems this was ignored. I am using iis, and Chrome browser

```
<location path="index.html">
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent> 
  <clientCache
    cacheControlMode="DisableCache"
     cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:00:00" /.  
    > 
   </staticContent> 
    <httpProtocol> 
     <customHeaders>
     <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
     <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" /> 
      <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
      </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
       </system.webServer> 
       </location>
```

Should this code go in index.html? Is there another way to make cache control work everytime flawlessly?

Comment: i too face this issue, only way is hard refresh.
all angular projects have this issue. files in asset directory is not compiled by angular so the fingerprint is not added to them, hence caching is a issue. may be using a gulp script before angular build to hash the assets can solve the problem.

Comment: So the config file or meta tags didn't work for you either?

Comment: Have you tried to remove location attribute and disable IIS static compression? You configuration works fine on my side if I build and deploy the release version to my IIS. Please remember to clean browser cache when you update IIS configuration.